# How would society react to a virus that makes you ugly?

Tags: society

In 2017, a mad scientist (let's call him Brad) creates a [chimera virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_(virus)). This virus is not lethal. It was designed by Brad to deteriorate and darken the skin and trigger the loss of 100% of body hair. This plague is named TRP405. By the time the disease is discovered, 95% of the human population is infected and symptoms have started to manifest. Assume a cure cannot be quickly found. Now everyone is ugly. How would the world react?

What would happen to...

- narcissistic people?
- to the few people not infected who still look normal?
- to the beauty industry?

Also, are people who are already ugly before the virus happy in this new era?

Keep in mind that my virus does not harm the human body outside of symptoms.

Comment: Why black = ugly in your question? I know some gorgeous, red hot models that happen to be black. If you mean something like charcoal black, not the naturally occurring skin tone, edit to make that clear. Because now it seems mildly racist and I hope this wasn't your intention. Also, I'm bald. Ugly? Gee thanks...

Comment: Yes charcoal black and old man skin.And loss of 100% of body hair,Eyelashes,Eyebrows etc etc.

Comment: They'd probably still try to cure it, I don't know. Just because the scientist who made it died, doesn't mean all hope is lost.

Comment: Lets say he used alien dna and nobody knows where are the samples.

Comment: Ugly is in the eye of the beholder.  Look at the number of people who for instance pay good money to (IMHO) disfigure themselves with tattoos.  You'd probably start a subculture in which the effects of this virus are seen as "cool", and people would compete for the most severe symptoms.

Comment: Infected hair and dead skin are highly contagious due to the nature of the alien dna.

Comment: Humans are quite adaptable to body changes, especially if the majority of the population is affected. Changes that cause western civilization people retching like lip plates and lotus feet were/are considered beautiful. There are also many people working in fields with disfigured people (e.g. WWI soldiers, skin diseases) which have grown accustomed to the sight. Loss of body hair and evenly skin darkening itself (even to unusual colors like green or blue) won't make you ugly, only unusual (Remember Avatar ?). So the new look would be "normal" and the unaffected exceptions.

Comment: I'd suggest some historical research on how people scarred by smallpox were treated. (I don't know, other than  that severe facial scarring was common back then).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it this way - ugly has many definitions. A lot of people are already "ugly" and so this virus won't affect that many people. On top of that, there is no way that humans won't find a way to fix this eventually. If it has to do with genetics, and there is a certain population of the world that isn't affected, then they will definitely solve the problem. The question is just when.

**How the World Will React**

People will obviously be horrified, as you will expect and will try to do something about it - making the cosmetics industry skyrocket and lots of money going to research how to fix it. Also, people who are already ugly won't really care that much because a lot of them have realized that "they are ugly" and go on their lives already knowing that they have talent elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, even if the cure IS destroyed Immunologists could still develop some sort of cure (or a vaccine for those nonimmune people that STILL haven't contracted the disease).

Narcissists across the globe would mentally break down as their ONLY redeeming qualities have been "stolen" from them. The global suicide rate (if that's even a thing) would increase to heights never-before-seen

(If teens are willing to commit suicide just because they're being bullied or if someone tells them that their fat then just IMAGINE what this would cause).

Racism would still exist (if you were wondering) as people who were affected to a lesser degree would berate and demean those that were "hit harder" by the disease.

The clothing industry would increase in profitability as people would want to cover up their "ugliness". Some people would even go as far as to wear masks in public.

I hope you enjoyed my answer!